# One matched route overrides another, but shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, routes

In routes.rb, I have:

```
[some routes]

match '/me' => "scores#all_athlete_scores", :constraints => LoggedInChecker
devise_scope :user do
  match '/me' => "devise/sessions#new"
end

match '/scores/athlete/:id', :to =>"scores#all_athlete_scores", :as => "all_athlete_scores"

[some more routes]
```

LoggedInChecker returns true if the user is logged in, and false if it's not.  If false, the second route picks it up and sends the user to a login page.

In scores_controller_test.rb, I have:

```
def test_get_all_athlete_scores
   [set up]
   get :all_athlete_scores, :id => @user
end
```

The weird part is that request.filtered_parameters[:full_path] in scores_controller_test is /me?id=@user.id, not /scores/athlete/:id'.

If I change routes.rb to be:

```
[some routes]

match '/scores/athlete/:id', :to =>"scores#all_athlete_scores", :as => "all_athlete_scores"

match '/me' => "scores#all_athlete_scores", :constraints => LoggedInChecker
devise_scope :user do
  match '/me' => "devise/sessions#new"
end

[some more routes]
```

The test works fine and request.filtered_parameters[:full_path] = /scores/athlete/:id.

Totally baffled by this - /me should not be matched when a GET is made to all_athlete_scores.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kareem,

I think the confusion is in the fact that you have a method as well as a named route 'all_athlete_scores'.

```
get :all_athlete_scores, :id => @user
```

calls the method all_athlete_scores rather than the named route, which is what you are expecting.

Probably should just test the functionality of that method within this test and leave the testing of routes to another test.

Hope that helps!